# How to map over an object's properties in order to get an array of data-items where both key and value are assigned each as value to a separate key?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, mapping, key-value

I'm dynamically calling blog categories and the number of posts that have those categories. I need an object called tabs to contain the category Titles called `categoryTitle` and the number of posts called `count` that have that category.  I would like the final array of objects to look like this:

```
   const tabs = [
          { categoryTitle: "blonde", count: "2"},
          { categoryTitle: "corrections", count: "2" },
          { categoryTitle: "offer", count: "1" },
          { categoryTitle: "products", count: "1" },
          { categoryTitle: "style", count: "1" },
        ];
```

How would I loop through these two objects below to create an object like above? Or should I build a class and pass the objects in ?

```
{blonde: 2, corrections: 2, offers: 1, products: 1, style: 1}
```

Comment: Hey, can you share what you've tried? This site is for getting help when you're stuck rather than asking for someone to code it for you, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. That might be the reason for the downvotes...

Comment: @guyzo I added an answer, Hope that will work as per your expectation.

Comment: `Object.entries({ blonde: 2, corrections: 2, offers: 1, products: 1, style: 1 }).map(([key, value]) => ({ categoryTitle: key, count: String(value) }));`

Comment: @guyzo ... From all the provided answers / solutions / approaches are there any questions left?

Answer (score 0):

Given what I can understand from the context, here's the code. If it doesn't work, please include that case in your question.

```
let oldObj = { blonde: 2, corrections: 2, offers: 1, products: 1, style: 1 };
const keys = Object.keys(oldObj);
const values = Object.values(oldObj);
let newObj = [];
for (i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    newObj.push({ categoryTitle: keys[i], count: '' + values[i] });
}

console.log(newObj);
```

Comment: Thanks that worked but needed to define index with a let let                                        
 oldObj = { blonde: 2, corrections: 2, offers: 1, products: 1, style: 1 };
const keys = Object.keys(oldObj);
const values = Object.values(oldObj);
let newObj = [];
for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    newObj.push({ categoryTitle: keys[i], count: '' + values[i] });
}

console.log(newObj);

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this by using [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method along with [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

Demo **:**

```js
const obj = {
    blonde: 2,
  corrections: 2,
  offers: 1,
  products: 1,
  style: 1
};

const tabs = Object.keys(obj).map(key => {
    return {
    categoryTitle: key,
    count: obj[key]
  }
});

console.log(tabs);
```

Answer (score 0):

An approach was to [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the provided object's [`entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) (key-value pairs) and assign `key` and `value` according to the OP's requirements (including the `string` typecast of `value`).

```js
console.log(
  Object
    .entries({
      blonde: 2,
      corrections: 2,
      offers: 1,
      products: 1,
      style: 1,
    })
    .map(([key, value]) => ({
      categoryTitle: key,
      count: String(value),
    }))
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```